# Error template binding Angular 2 in Safari

Tags: javascript, angular, safari

I'm developing a basic app in Angular2 but I have problems only in Safari. I have two components, one of them make a server request to get data and other paint the data. To make that I am using ngIf and ngFor, but I dont know why, in Safari, I cannot see the results, until I click on some other components of my screen (like writing something in a input). I dont know if there is a related issue with this only in Safari, because in Chrome works great.

To paint data in the component I'm doing use of INPUT like this:

```
<list-hours [filtered]="filter" *ngIf="schedule.length" [hours]="schedule"></list-hours>
```

Where, 'hours' is the input, and 'schedule' is the data to paint. Even, I put a ngIf to assure paint data when it is available.

In the inner component, I'm making this to show data:

```
<ul class="list-hours">
    <li *ngFor="let hour of hours; let i = index;" [ngClass]="{'first': i===0}">
      item: {{hour}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Why only Safari not show the data?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If possible, please create a plunker.

Comment: sorry but the application is so heavy. I was checking that it could be a problem related with zone, but I'm not sure of this.

Comment: try subscribe `schedule` in listHoursComponent and see if console.log will give you anything.

Comment: Yes, I tried this like first solution but never show the console. It is something very strange, only works when I interact with other UI component inside the view